# What is the grammatical role of "his former sister-in-law on his arm"?

Tags: grammar, absolute-construction

> Mark walked into the hotel’s ballroom, **his former sister-in-law on his arm**. He smiled when he saw his brother’s smile freeze into a gremlin’s glare.

What would you say is the  grammatical function of *his former sister-in-law on his arm*?

Comment: Please make **unique** titles that actually reflect what your question is about. Generic titles don't help anyone help you!

Comment: What do you mean by "Epithet"? I'm not sure the word means what you think it means. I would strongly recommend you review the "[Uses of commas](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/owlprint/607/)" (there are many other resources out there. It's important that you show some research. Please explain what you specifically don't understand here.

Comment: It seems like a subordinate clause, maybe. I may not get how to discern which, maybe, subordinate clause?

Comment: Perhaps a **supplementary verbless clause.** E.g. *"The defendants sat on the dock, their heads in their hands"* (2002 *CGEL*, page 1359, [28.ii]). These verbless clauses can be interpreted as meaning "his former sister-in-law was on his arm" and "their heads were in their hands".

Comment: In any case, the clause is adverbial; it tells _how_ he walked into the ballroom.

Comment: The rhetorical function of supplementary verbless clauses such as *his former sister-in-law on his arm*  is to stop the reader in his tracks, to wonder just how tiny that woman on his arm might be. My guess -- about the size of a parrot, or a capuchin monkey.  As we can also see from the defendants who sit on the dock, *their heads in their hands*, such clauses usually refer to something very strange or odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called an **absolute construction**. An absolute construction is a clause or phrase that isn't grammatically joined to any particular word in the main sentence, the way an adjective usually modifies a noun, an adverb usually modifies a verb, a verb usually says something about its subject, etc. The word "absolute" comes from Latin roots meaning "released from, loose, separate", reflecting this loose relation with the rest of the sentence.

One could argue that "his former sister-in-law on his arm" is an adjectival phrase, modifying "Mark". One could also argue that it's an adverbial phrase, modifying "walked". I think it's best just to call it an absolute construction and leave it at that. It lacks an explicit grammatical connector, which would be "**with** his former sister-in-law on his arm". So, you have to understand its connection with the rest of the sentence purely from its meaning, not from grammatical cues.

Here are some more examples of absolute constructions:

> **The guests having arrived,** the party started.
>
> **His advisory committee satisfied at last,** John received his Ph.D.
>
> I went to the station and got some water myself, **the waitress being on break.**
>
> **A well-regulated militia being necessary to the security of a free state,** the right of the people to keep and bear arms shall not be infringed. [[2nd Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution#Late_20th_century_commentary) of U.S. Constitution; the absolute construction is famous for the ambiguity it creates regarding the scope of the main clause.]
>
> "What is best in life?" "To ride free on the open steppe, **a fleet horse beneath you, falcons at your wrist, and the wind in your hair.**" [Famous wrong answer, modified slightly from [Conan the Barbarian](https://youtu.be/6PQ6335puOc?t=11s)]

As you can see from the examples, the absolute construction usually has its own subject, separate from the subject of the main sentence. The subject is usually modified by a participle, the construction meaning "because of such-and-such …" or "while such-and-such was happening …" if it's a present participle, or "when such-and-such was complete" if it's a past participle. Your example is a little unusual in that it doesn't include a participle, like the last example above.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction) is some more information.